# Espresso providing NoMatchingViewException

Tags: android, ui-testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to test UI of my android app using Espresso but I encountered some troubles.
My tests yesterday were working correctly but today nothing is working.
Even this simple test doesn't work:

```
 onView(withId(R.id.login_btnSignup)).perform(click());
```

It gives "android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException:" even if in the emulator I can see it effectively perform that action correctly.
I've turned off in my emulator window annimation scale, transition animation scale and animator duration scale.
I've also watched other similar questions, but without result.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: This could be due to slower network speed. Try putting it in sleep for a few seconds to confirm it

Answer (score 0):

If you say that yesterday the tests were working and now they are not, I think you need to refresh your environment: clean project, recreate emulator, reinstall app. Tell me if I helped. On my end, this never happened. I am using Espresso for some time.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When you are trying to perform a click on the a view, it is critical that the view is currently visible in the display when the view is to be clicked.  A couple of things that can cause problems:

- The view being obscured because the soft keyboard is being displayed over the button.  This can be addressed by closing the soft keyboard before clicking:

  ```
  Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard();
  ```
- The view can be scrolled out of view which can be handled with:

  ```
  onView(withId(R.id.login_btnSignup)).perform(scrollTo()).perform(click());
  ```

Also to debug this issue, it may be difficult to tell that the button is actually being clicked.  Try putting a break point on the click handler and debug the test.